# Compute Christoffel symbols & Riemann tesors in Maple 17

Tags: computational-mathematics, maple, computer-algebra-systems

[image: This is a screenshot of the beginning]
I invented a metric tensor g and now I'm trying to compute my first Christoffel symbol but an error message is popping up "Error, bad index into matrix" Is there a way for maple to compute Christoffel symbols/Riemann/Einstein tensors automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the DifferentialGeometry package, specifically the Tensor sub-package.
http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DifferentialGeometry%2fTensor